# Can we introuduce aliases for template specializations?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Can we introduce an alias for a partial specialization? I mean something like that:

```
template <class T, class V>
class A{ };

typedef template <class T> A<T, int> MyPartialSpecializa<T>; 

int main(){ }
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f94f81ec7fa732cf)

But it doesn't work. What does the Standard say about that?

Comment: That's not even syntatically valid. `template<...>` goes before a *declaration*, never inside one. C++11 has alias templates: `template<class T> using Foo = A<T, int>;`.

Comment: @T.C. That's why I ask that question, because the construction I used was not valid. Maybe you can provide some reference...?

Comment: Annex A has all the grammar productions in the standard, or you can check the relevant clauses. But if you do not know about alias templates, then you should really be reading a decent C++11 book, not the standard.

Answer (score 4):

You need an alias template for this

```
template <class T, class V>
class A{ };

template <class T>
using MyPartialSpecializa = A<T, int>; 

int main()
{ 
  MyPartialSpecializa<double> a;
}
```